# Attaching both mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers using jQuery

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, event-handling

I'm a newbie to javascript, and day after day, I try to write better code with jQuery.

For example, I wrote this code earlier:

```
$$foo= $(".foo");

$$foo.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('h1').addClass("hover");
});

$$foo.mouseleave(function() {
    $("h1").removeClass("hover");
});
```

What I want to happen with this code is when the mouse enters `.foo` the `h1` gets a new background color or any style applying on class, `hover`.

Another example:

```
$$foo= $(".foo");

$$foo.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('h1').addClass("hover");
    $(this).find('input').focus();
});

$$foo.mouseleave(function() {
    $("h1").removeClass("hover");
    $(".foo input").val('');
});
```

What I want to happen here is when the mouse enters `.foo` the input gets focus, and when mouse out the input's values are removed.

Both cases are working perfect, but I want to know if there is a better way to do this (mouse enter and mouse out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can use [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and passing 2 functions (mouseenter, mouseleave)
and u can shorten it also with [jQuery end](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

```
$('.foo').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('h1').addClass("hover").end().find('input').focus();            
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('h1').removeClass("hover").end().find('input').val('');            
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Shlomi, what about if the same code happen after click not hover

Comment: @JimmyTodd then u can use replace the **hover** with **toggle**

Comment: Note that the [`.toggle()` event binding function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was removed in v1.9.

Comment: @StefanBob - according to the doco the `.hover()` event binding method is still supported. Do you have a link to doco that says otherwise?